# How to automatically show method parameters on Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8

usually when I call a function/method in other IDEs that I use, a tooltip showing the required and optional methods appears when I type the opening "(" of the method call. For example, when I call this method

```
public void thismethod(String arg1, int arg2) { ... 
}
```

in this statement

```
thismethod(
```

I usually expect a tooltip like this

(**String arg1**, int arg2)

to show up. However, this doesn't happen for me in Netbeans, which is the IDE that I **need** to use for programming in Java. Thanks.

Comment: try ctrl+p short cut

Comment: post it as Answer so that it can be marked solved, please.